# How to define the partial of the logarithm of a density operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, hamiltonian, density-operator

I've been thinking about self-information ($I:=-\log (\rho)$) lately and I have a question on how to evaluate the derivative of such an operator... I realize that $i\hbar(\partial/\partial t)\rho=[H,\rho]$. However, I have a question about defining $\partial_0\log(\rho)$ (with $\partial_0$ the partial with respect to $x^0=ct$): If $$[i\hbar\rho^{-1}(\partial/\partial t)\rho]\psi=[\rho^{-1}(H\rho-\rho H)]\psi=[\rho^{-1}H\rho]\psi-H\psi=\rho^{-1}(H\rho)\psi+\rho^{-1}\rho H\psi-H\psi=[\rho^{-1}H\rho]\psi$$ and $$[i\hbar[(\partial/\partial t)\rho]\rho^{-1}]\psi=[(H\rho-\rho H)\rho^{-1}]\psi=[H-\rho H\rho^{-1}]\psi=H\psi+\rho^{-1}(H\rho)\psi-H\psi=[\rho^{-1}H\rho]\psi,$$ (with $\psi$ the wave-function and such that the fact that $H(\rho\psi)=(H\rho)\psi+\rho(H\psi)$ has been used with $(H\rho)$ meaning the Hamiltonian acting only upon $\rho$ and not upon $\psi$ [i.e., the parenthesis are no longer associative]) then, as $i\hbar \rho^{-1}(\partial/\partial t)\rho = i\hbar [(\partial/\partial t)\rho]\rho^{-1}$, can one accurately define $i\hbar \partial_0 \ln(\rho):=i\hbar \rho^{-1}\partial_0 \rho$? If not, then how should $\partial_0 \ln(\rho)$ be defined?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not sure I follow your calculations, is $\partial_0$ the time derivative? What is $\psi$? Where does $H\psi$ go in the calculations when you use an arrow $\rightarrow$? If I understand correctly, you show that $[\rho^{-1},\partial_t \rho]=0$, why do you think this implies something about the derivative of $\log\rho$? In short, I think I need more context.

Comment: Anyway, see this [Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723262/explicit-proof-of-the-derivative-of-a-matrix-logarithm), the expression is more complicated

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This should really help!

Comment: I now see that if your claim $[\rho^{-1},\rho']=0$ is correct, then the log does reduce to what you claim it reduces to! I'm trying to see why the claim is correct.

Comment: It hinges upon what is basically the Leibniz product differentiation rule which (I think) applies since both $\rho$ and $\psi$ are states.

Comment: you use the fact $H(\rho\psi)=(H\rho)\psi+\rho (H\psi)$. I don't see where this comes from. $H$ and $\rho$ are both matrices (or linear operators), why should they compose as differential operators?

Comment: When applied to a state $\psi$, $H\psi=i\hbar (\partial/\partial t)\psi$, so I think that if $H$ acts upon states, it will act as a differential operator. I'm not totally sure about acting on $\rho$, but I think that if $\rho=\sum |k\rangle \langle k|$ with $\psi=\langle x|k\rangle$ then it should work...

Comment: @PrawwarP that's wrong, $i\hbar\partial_t \rho = [H,\rho]\neq H\rho$. The Hamiltonian is *not* the same as the time derivative.

Comment: That's not what I meant: I basically applied $H$ to a product of states ($\rho \psi$). In that case, wouldn't $H$ have the same property of a time derivative? (Note that I used that $i\hbar \partial_t \rho=[H,\rho]$ in the derivation as opposed to claiming $i\hbar \partial_t \rho=H\rho$.)

Comment: No, $H$ is not the same as $\partial_t$ so you cannot just use the chain rule.

Comment: Even when $H$ is being applied to states? The chain rule is what's used to derive $i\hbar \partial_t \rho=[H,\rho]$ because $\rho$ is a product of states?